# Transcendence degree of fraction field

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra

Let $k$ be a field and $p \in k[x_1, \dots, x_n]$ an irreducible element. Is there an elementary way to prove that $\operatorname{tr.deg}_k \mbox{Frac}(k[x_1, \dots, x_n]/(p)) = n-1$?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pick one variable say $x_n$ which occurs in $p$ then consider the quotient as an algebraic extension of a field of transcendence degree $n-1$.

Comment: I assume that you want to consider the field $\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}])$. But does it inject into $\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(p))$? Equivalently, why are $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}$ algebraically independent over $k$ in $\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(p))$? Is this true at all? I think that we might have to use other variables, namely the ones in the proof of Noether-Normalization.

Comment: You are just taking an algebraic extension of $k(x_1\ldots x_{n-1})$. Since we are talking about independence over $k$, definition of independence reads the same in both the field and its extension.

Comment: It is not clear (to me) why $K=\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]/(p))$ is an extension of $\mathrm{Frac}(k[x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}])$. For this we would have to prove that $x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1} \in K$ in are algebraically independent over $k$. Equivalently, if $q \in k[x_1,\dotsc,x_{n-1}]$ and $p | q$ in $k[x_1,\dotsc,x_n]$, then $q=0$. I assume that this is true because $x_n$ appears in $p$, but it doesn't seem to be completely formal.

Comment: There are probably different ways of explaining this, here is the one that makes sense to me, and simplifying the notation, we have a ring $k[x,y]$ and an irreducible polynomial $p(y,x)$ we now construct the field $k(x)[y]/(p)$. This is adding a root of $p$, let us write it as $k(x,\alpha)$ where $\alpha$ is the root. Now we have a map $k[x,y]\rightarrow k(x,\alpha)$ defined by $y\mapsto \alpha$. The kernel of the map is $(p)$ and so we have an inclusion $k[x,y]/(p) \subseteq k(x,\alpha)$ and the image is clearly $k[x,\alpha]$, so we are reduced to $k(x,\alpha)=\Frac k[x,\alpha]$ its clear.

Comment: It's completely formal. It's enough to use de degree function in $k[x_1,\dots,x_{n-1}][x_n]$, which is well-defined.